# How to improve the precision of this base converter function on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, precision, radix, base-conversion

I'm trying to create a function on Matlab that converts a base 10 (decimal) real number into another base.

I wrote this function:

```
function [converted_number] = base_converter(base,number,digits)

format longG

separator=' ';
radix_character='.';

digits=digits-1;

integer_part=floor(number);
fractional_part=number-integer_part;

converted_number='';

if integer_part==0
    converted_number=['0'];
end

while integer_part~=0

    converted_number=[converted_number,separator,num2str(mod(integer_part,base))];
    integer_part=(integer_part-mod(integer_part,base))./base;

end

converted_number=[converted_number,separator,radix_character];

while fractional_part~=0 && digits~=0

    fractional_part=fractional_part.*base;
    converted_number=[converted_number,separator,num2str(floor(fractional_part))];
    fractional_part=fractional_part-floor(fractional_part);
    digits=digits-1;    

end

end
```

It works.

But the problem is that it doesn't give me enough precision.

For example:

```
base_converter(12,1./11,50)

ans =

0 . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 11 10 1 11 5 1 11 0 3 11 3
```

(the 1s should be repeating indefinitely)

It has a precision of about 10^(-16) only. I would need much more precision.

I put the format which to the best of my knowledge gives the most precision: longG.

Maybe there is another format which gives even more precision?

Or maybe there is a way to modify my function so that it would have an arbitrary precision?

Comment: [format](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) longG only has an impact on the apperance of a number, as far as i know.

Comment: Anyhow, [Matlab uses double precision by default](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html). But you can check with `isa(num,'double')`